# React, Jest: simulate submit form unit test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I've stuck with the simple test case and cannot find out the cause it doesn't work.
There is the component which I would like to test:

```
export class SignInForm extends Component {

   onSubmit = (user) => {
       console.log('THERE----', this.props.signin);  // ---> i saw it during testing
       this.props.signin();
   };

   render() {
       return (
           <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              {formApi => (
                  <form onSubmit={formApi.submitForm}>
                       <InputFieldGroup field="identifier" label="Username/Email"/>
                       <InputFieldGroup field="password" label="Password" type="password"/>
                       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                   </form>
               )}
           </Form>
       );
   }
```

}

and there's my test case.

```
it('should render in proper way', () => {

    const signinMock = jest.fn();

    const props = {
        signin: signinMock
    };

    const component = mount(<SignInForm {...props}/>);


    component.find('form').simulate('submit');

    console.log(signinMock.mock.calls); // ---> saw empty array []
});
```

In this case I would expect that signinMock was invoked at once. But I saw the empty array of calls, but during launching test I saw the console log of component method: console.log('THERE----', this.props.signin); and I saw the mock function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` executes before the event handlers and hence you see an empty array. The following code would allow the event handlers to execute and then you can do the assertion.

```
setTimeout(()=> {
    expect(signinMock.mock.calls.length).to.equal(1);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. It saves my time.